# Is there a concept of working-days in the Nodatime library?

Tags: nodatime

Is there a concept of working-days in the Nodatime library?

What I would like to do is to somehow state that there is 5 working-days in a calender week, and then be able to ask something like:

From [any given date] + 10 working-days what is the end date?

or

From [this calender date] to [that calender date] how many working-days are in that interval?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this doesn't exist as you described it.  However, you can certainly use Noda Time's `LocalDate` object and implement your own logic.  An `O(n)` implementation would simply use `LocalDate.DayOfWeek` and a `for` loop.  I'm sure one could create an `O(1)` implementation easily as well.

Comment: I suspect the O(1) implementation would be fiddly - but more important, it wouldn't include public holidays, which I suspect *most* uses for "working days" would want to take account of.

Comment: This is our earliest open issue, btw: https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/issues/6 :)

Comment: @JonSkeet - I had forgotten, but a recent S.O. comment reminded me that I modeled some holiday logic a couple of years ago here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33374874/634824.  Maybe something like that would be useful?

Comment: Almost certainly. Especially if we can easily add support for any very common file formats of holidays...